# Styling in angular

Tags: angular, user-interface, styles

I'm new to angular design and styling. I need to make design in a new project using existing styles. My college that left few months ago used the styles in his project. I take his styles but they are not working in my project although I installed ui-bootstrap: npm install angular-ui-bootstrap

Example of the existing styles.css:

```
        .ui-contextmenu {
      background-color: red !important;
    }
         body .ui-dropdown {
      color: white !important;
    }
```

When I inspect the styles in my project I see that component already use styles starting with 'p', not 'ui', for example:

```
.p-contextmenu {}, .p-dropdown{}, etc
```

I managed to give styles to components by adding ::ng-deep in front of .p-dropdown, p-table, etc.
Both of us are using primeng library so it's the same type of components.
Could you please help me understand how the styles are working in angular. It's very unintuitive for me.
What should I do to be able to use his styles, starting with ui-? Why do styles of components in my project start with p-? Please advise what to read to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `angular.json` file, there is a field `styles`, this is the place that you can add css, and the project will take this config when build project.
e.g:

```
"styles": [
"./node_modules/@somelib/styles/styles.css",
]
```

Comment: I have in my angular.json file this fileld: 
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "./node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-alt/theme.css",
              "./node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
                                     
In old project almost the same :
"styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "./node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "./node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css",
                etc

            ],

Comment: maybe you can check what's in `src/styles.css` in the old project. normally `styles` field is the place to go when you want to use some lib's style